# Remove last line of file by any user, owned by root

Tags: text-processing, sed, ed

I have a file with permissions `666` so users can edit it with a different script. This works.
I need to script to remove the last line of the file, however this is not working as using something like `sed` tris to create a file first and move it in place. Users are unable to do that.

Is there a way I can edit the file in place to remove the last line without moving a new file in its place?

Comment: Can you just place the file in a directory with 777 permissions? Also. please[edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. While that likely won't change the permissions issues (unless you're using Windows or an NTFS file system or something like that) it will help us know what tools you may have available.

Comment: And did you try sed -i '$d' file in order to modified the file in place ?

Comment: @admstg The issue is that this gives you a new file with a new inode number. The user, I believe, wants to overwrite the _existing_ file, not create a new file.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question was tagged with [ed](/questions/tagged/ed), the following shows how to perform the edit on the file in an in-place fashion using the `ed` editor:

```bash
printf '%s\n' d w q | ed -s file
```

When starting an editing session with `ed`, the editor always places you at the last line of the opened file. To delete the last line of the file, we may therefore delete the *current* line with `d`, write back the modified buffer to the file with `w`, and quit with `q`. Most implementations of the `ed` editor (but not BusyBox `ed`) allows you to use the non-standard combined command `wq` in place of `w` followed by `q`.

This does not create a new file (the resulting file has the same inode number as the original file).

Answer (score 2):

You could truncate it in place. On a GNU system:

```
truncate -s -"$(tail -n1 file | wc -c)" file
```

`truncate -<n>` shaves *<n>* bytes off the end of a file. Here *<n>* is computed from the length in bytes of the last line as returned by `wc`.

Portably, you could use `perl` to do the truncating:

```
tail -n1 file | perl -ne '
  if (seek(STDOUT, -length, 2)) {
    truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT or die "truncate: $!\n"
  } else {
    die "seek: $!\n"
  }' 1<> file
```

Note that it does not rewrite the contents of the file so is much more efficient than `sed`-based approaches (and also safer in the face of non-text files or full filesystems).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out
send output of regular sed command to a local file of the user (temp file), then cat the file as output to the file in question.

`sed '$d' /path/to/file > ./tempfile; cat ./tempfile > /path/to/file`

Comment: Alternatively `cp file file.tmp && sed '$d' file.tmp >file && rm -f file.tmp`.

Comment: You probably want to use `mktemp` to create a unique temp file and not rely on a hardcoded name that might be used for something else.

Comment: @Kusalananda if making a copy of the file was possible, then sed -i would have worked. User isn't allowed to make a new file in that folder. I actually tried sed -i and it gave me this: "sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sedmkKIIz: Permission denied".

Comment: @seshoumara As far as I understand, the issue is not creating new files in the directory, but avoiding replacing the original file with a new file. You can see that the command in this answer and in my comment above leaves the original file in place with the same inode number (the inode number is shown in the output of `ls -i`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it in sed, without creating a temporary file, by using the 'w' command. This way the file's inode number isn't changed. A better version, B), that is easier to use, especially in scripts, is to assign first the name of the file to a variable.

```
A) cat file|sed -ne '1h;${x;wfile' -e '};1!H'
B) file="test.txt";cat "$file"|sed -ne '1h;${x;w'"$file" -e '};1!H'
```

The file is passed to cat so that sed reads input from the pipe and not directly from the file, which we want to modify. Each input line sed reads is stored in the hold space. However, at the end of the input the hold space is written to the file before the last line is stored.